# How can I create a global command for a user raw_input(); access inventory list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm not really 100% sure how to ask the question, but here goes:

I'm going through Learn Python the Hard Way, and I'm on Ex. 45, where I'm supposed to create a text-based game on my own. I've had to pull someone else's code to make an inventory (which I will supply the code for below), but I cannot for the life of me figure out this: if the user types "inventory" in any raw_input() (across multiple classes), how can I get it to display the contents of the inventory? All I can think of would be a more complex version of this:

```
if raw_input() == "inventory"
    print ???
```

but I do not know how to have the game display inventory (the ???) or allow "inventory" to become a global command...
I know this looks very, very barebones, but I would not be coming here unless I researched and tried to find the answer myself. Thank you to anyone who can help out, this is getting frustrating!

Here's the inventory system I'm using:

```
class Item(object):
  def __init__(self, name, quantity=1):
    self.name = name
    self.raw = name.strip().lower()
    self.quantity = quantity

class Container(object):
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.inside = {}

  def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.inside.items())

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.inside)

  def __contains__(self, item):
    return item.raw in self.inside

  def __getitem__(self, item):
    return self.inside[item.raw]

  def __setitem__(self, item, value):
    self.inside[item.raw] = value
    return self[item]

  def add(self, item, quantity=1):
    if quantity < 0:
        print "ERROR."
    if item in self:
        self[item].quantity += quantity
    else:
        self[item] = item           

inventory = Container("Inventory")

spare_key = Item("SPARE KEY", 1)
rock = Item("ROCK", 1)

print(spare_key in inventory)
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to print the contents of an instance of the `Container` class:

```
print "Inventory: [" + ",".join((item[1].name for item in inventory)) + "]"
```

Consider changing this function:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.inside.items())
```

to this:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.inside.values())
```

Usually you would expect that iterating over an inventory yields just items, not tuples with item's name and item.